# Magento 2 - Get custom attribute within .phtml file using Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation class?

Tags: magento2, attributes, phtml, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I am trying to get a custom attribute value within my phtml file but struggling to get this to work? `getData() & getCustomAttribute()` doesn't seem to work. I believe this is because I am using the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation` class to loop through my categories?

Can anyone advise how I can get my custom attribute value within my loop in my `product-categories.phtml`?

> default.xml within my theme

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation" name="product.categories" template="Magento_Theme::html/product-categories.phtml"></block>
```

> product-categories.phtml

```
<?php
if (!$block->getCategory()) {
    return;
}
$_categories = $block->getCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
$_count = is_array($_categories) ? count($_categories) : $_categories->count();
if ($_count) {
    ?>
    <ul class="list-quicklinks row med-gutter">
        <?php 
        foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
            if ($_category->getIsActive()) {
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    <?php
                    //$short_description = $_category->getData('short_category_description');
                    //$short_description = $_category->getCustomAttribute('short_category_description');
                    //$short_description = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($_category, '', 'short_category_description');
                    ?>
                    <p><?php // echo $short_description; ?></p> 
                </li>
                <?php 
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

```
namespace Autosmart\CategoryAttributes\Model;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
{
    public function getShortCategoryDescription()
    {            
        //return "working";  
        return $this->_getAttribute('category_short_description');
    }
}
```

I've created a modal with custom function `getShortCategoryDescription()` which I can call by `$_category->getShortCategoryDescription()` however I am unsure how to get this to return my short description attribute. The above code gives me an error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Module\CategoryAttributes\Model\Category\Interceptor::_getAttribute
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom template try this to get the custom attribute value.

```
 $block->getCategory()->getChildrenCategories()->getAttribute([your_custom_attribute_code_name]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Magento 2 getChildrenCategories get's a model with limited amount of attributes inside them, only a few like: *url_key, name, all_children, is_anchor and position*

you should be able to get the category child id and load from that your custom attribute, you'll need a custom function that loads a category from ID:

getChildren (instead of getChildrenCategories) returns the list of ids of the child categories of the current category.

```
$_childCategory = $block->getCategoryFromId($_category->getId());
$_childCategory->getData('Custom_attribute')
```

or you can just rewrite the getChildrenCategories so it will take your custom attribute too